# php submit form is not redirecting given action, it redirects to home page.. I use Yii 2, pretty url.. But I don't want to use yii2 submit form

Tags: php, forms, yii2

php submit form is not redirecting given action, it redirects to home page..  I use Yii 2, pretty URL.. But I don't want to use yii2 submit form.. Kindly help me on this.. I'm not sure if we can use core php form in Yii 2 framework

````
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
  
    <body>
        <form action = "/syllabus/lms/index" method = "post">
              
            Author : <input type = "text" name = "author" 
              placeholder = "Author's Name" />
                  
            <br><br>
              
            Number of published Article : <input type = "number"
              name = "num_article" placeholder = "Published Article" />
                  
            <br><br>
              
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "test";
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the given action parameter.
Change this line of code:

```html
<form action = "/syllabus/lms/index" method = "post">
```

To:

```html
<form action = "syllabus/lms/index.php" method = "post">
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. I tried this also, it redirects to 404..  I'm using a pretty URL in my app. will that affect ?